# Unsure of Displaying Unique Data in Singly Linked List

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm having trouble understanding what I should do in order to print all of the unique data in a Singly/Linear Linked List.

For instance, what if I had the following data:
1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3

In a linear linked list, I would have to print 1 -> 2 -> 3

Here is my code for the struct for an SLL/LLL node.

```
struct node
{
     int data;
     node * next;
};
```

Here is my code for adding it

```
add(int data)
{
     if (!head)
     {
          head = new node;
          head -> data = data;
     }  
     else
     {
          add(head);
     }
}

add(node *& head)
 {
      if (!head)
      {
           return;
      }

      node * front = head -> next;

      if (!head -> next)
      {
           front = new node;
           front -> data = 
           head -> next = front;
           return;
      }

      add(head -> next);
}
```

Here is my code for displaying it:

```
void displayUnique()
{
     if (!head)
     {      
          return;
     }

     return dU(head);
}

void dU(node * head)
{
     if (!head)
     {
          return;
     }

cout << head -> data << " ";

return dU(head -> next);
}
```

Am I supposed to sort the linear linked list or some sort?

Comment: Are you forced to add duplicates to the list?

Comment: If the list is ordered, then you have to keep track of the last value displayed and not display any nodes which have the same value. When the value changes, display it and set the last value to the new value.

Comment: The list always has at least one duplicate. For instance, 5 -> 6 -> 5 -> 10 -> NULL; @johnelemans, the list is initially not ordered (randomly generated in fact)

Comment: you can iterate over all the element before printing or the element using a temporary object in print() function

Comment: that's right, building a new list is your only option.

Comment: Another option would be to print the first instance only and keep track of what you have seen before.

Comment: @johnelemans you are suggesting that I have a build function and a check function after each individual node. Add a node to a dest_head and then check all of the src_head for copies? I'm also curious about this efficiency for that build function. Would it be O(n^2)?

Comment: This will probably freak out any instructor that has you building a linked list, but when you print, [maintain a `std::set` of the values you've seen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). For each link, 1. check if the set contains the value. 2. If it does not contain the value, print the value and add the value to the set so you won't print it next time. 3. Proceed to the next link.

Comment: I'm not able to use any outside libraries. I'm trying to do this from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so there are couple approaches:

**1. The order of the list does not matter**

If the order is irrelevant, then the fastest approach would be to sort your list by `node.data`. This gives you O(n**log* n) complexity. (Additionally, if this is the case, I would encourage you to modify your `add(node *& head)` is the way it inserts new `node` in place that keeps the list sorted). After that, you can just keep track of previously displayed value and check whether or not it's the same. If it is, skip to the next node. If not, display current one and remember what you displayed. This is O(n).

**2. The order of the list does matter**

Here the problem gets a little bit more complicated. You will need either additional time complexity (I would unfortunately aim at O(n^2)) or additional memory. My personal approach would be: create temporary `std::set` that will remember what numbers you have already displayed and each time you iterate through list (feel free to correct me if "iteration through list" is not a valid term), you will check whether or not the candidate (current `node.data`) has already been displayed, thus, is recorded in your `std::set`. Searching through `std::set` is O(n**log* n), so it's really not that bad (however keep in mind that inserting a value into set takes a little more time than, for example, inserting value into `std::vector`).

If I missed something (obvious or not) feel free to correct or ask me in the comments.